# How to create a binary mask in keras using a network for provided indices

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a network in Keras that takes an image as an input image of size 176x208 and outputs 35 indices example

```
[[121  55 115  82  59  84  85  77 155  15  29 105  48  97 158  32 104  39 111 110  47   1  45   0 120 154 130  98 118  95 160  22  63  86  80]]
```

I want to create another network that takes these indices and creates a binary mask image of shape 176x208. The indices shown in this output correspond to columns.

How can I create this network?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a network in Keras to generate a binary mask image from indices by using a fully connected layer followed by a reshaping layer.

First, you can use a fully connected (dense) layer with a single output unit, with a sigmoid activation function. This will take the input indices and produce a continuous output between 0 and 1 for each pixel of the binary mask.

Then, you can use a reshaping layer to reshape the output of the dense layer to the desired image shape (176x208). This reshaping layer will convert the output of the dense layer, which is a 1-D array, into a 2-D image of shape (176x208).

For example, the network architecture could be defined as follows:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Reshape

    input_indices = Input(shape=(35,))
    x = Dense(176*208, activation='sigmoid')(input_indices)
    output_image = Reshape((176,208))(x)
    model = Model(inputs=input_indices, outputs=output_image)
```

You will also have to reshape the input indices to match the input shape of the model, which is (35,), before passing it to the model.

You might also want to consider using a different activation function, such as 'relu' or 'tanh' to get different results.